# Python: finding an element in a list

Tags: python, list

What is a good way to find the index of an element in a list in Python?
Note that the list may not be sorted.

Is there a way to specify what comparison operator to use?

Comment: Can unmark this one as duplicated, the questions and answers don't handle the case of class instances that match a criteria.

Comment: Also finding the index of an item in a list is not the same thing as finding the item in a list.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The best way is probably to use the [list method .index](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

For the objects in the list, you can do something like:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.Value == other.Value
```

with any special processing you need.

You can also use a for/in statement with enumerate(arr)

Example of finding the index of an item that has value > 100.

```
for index, item in enumerate(arr):
    if item > 100:
        return index, item
```

[Source](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread174502.html)

Answer (score 316):

From [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html):

```
>>> li
['a', 'b', 'new', 'mpilgrim', 'z', 'example', 'new', 'two', 'elements']
>>> li.index("example")
5
```

Comment: But this code gives error when element is not in the list.In current example context if I search for 'three' (i.e: li.index('three')) gives error.

Comment: You can catch the error to detect when something isn't in the list. `try: li.index("three") except ValueError: found = false`

Comment: if you really want to find the index then, first check element in array if True then only do => li.index("example")

Answer (score 177):

If you just want to find out if an element is contained in the list or not:

```
>>> li
['a', 'b', 'new', 'mpilgrim', 'z', 'example', 'new', 'two', 'elements']
>>> 'example' in li
True
>>> 'damn' in li
False
```

Answer (score 62):

Here is another way using list comprehension (some people might find it debatable). It is very approachable for simple tests, e.g. comparisons on object attributes (which I need a lot):

```
el = [x for x in mylist if x.attr == "foo"][0]
```

Of course this assumes the existence (and, actually, uniqueness) of a suitable element in the list.

Comment: `el = [x for x in mylist if x.attr == "foo"]`

`if el: do something with el[0]`

solves the "existence" problem

Comment: `el = next((x for x in mylist if x.attr == "foo"), None)` if you want to receive a value even when doesn't exist

Comment: `[*[label_set for label_set in prediction_label_sets if x == 3], None][0]` If you want it to fallback to none, without using an iterator. Not sure if it's simpler or harder.

Answer (score 19):

assuming you want to find a value in a numpy array,
I guess something like this might work:

```
Numpy.where(arr=="value")[0]
```

Comment: doesn't work for multidimensional arrays if you're looking for a specific row, e.g. `arr = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])` if you do `np.where(arr == [0,1,0])` it doesn't give the right result

Comment: @ierdna, don't you need to supply `axis=0` or `axis=1`?

Answer (score 8):

There is the `index` method, `i = array.index(value)`, but I don't think you can specify a custom comparison operator. It wouldn't be hard to write your own function to do so, though:

```
def custom_index(array, compare_function):
    for i, v in enumerate(array):
        if compare_function(v):
            return i
```

Answer (score 6):

I use function for returning index for the matching element (Python 2.6):

```
def index(l, f):
     return next((i for i in xrange(len(l)) if f(l[i])), None)
```

Then use it via lambda function for retrieving needed element by any required equation e.g. by using element name.

```
element = mylist[index(mylist, lambda item: item["name"] == "my name")]
```

If i need to use it in several places in my code i just define specific find function e.g. for finding element by name:

```
def find_name(l, name):
     return l[index(l, lambda item: item["name"] == name)]
```

And then it is quite easy and readable:

```
element = find_name(mylist,"my name")
```

Answer (score 4):

The index method of a list will do this for you. If you want to guarantee order, sort the list first using `sorted()`. Sorted accepts a cmp or key parameter to dictate how the sorting will happen:

```
a = [5, 4, 3]
print sorted(a).index(5)
```

Or:

```
a = ['one', 'aardvark', 'a']
print sorted(a, key=len).index('a')
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this by adapting some tutos. Thanks to google, and to all of you ;)

```
def findall(L, test):
    i=0
    indices = []
    while(True):
        try:
            # next value in list passing the test
            nextvalue = filter(test, L[i:])[0]

            # add index of this value in the index list,
            # by searching the value in L[i:] 
            indices.append(L.index(nextvalue, i))

            # iterate i, that is the next index from where to search
            i=indices[-1]+1
        #when there is no further "good value", filter returns [],
        # hence there is an out of range exeption
        except IndexError:
            return indices
```

A very simple use:

```
a = [0,0,2,1]
ind = findall(a, lambda x:x>0))

[2, 3]
```

P.S. scuse my english

Answer (score 2):

how's this one?

```
def global_index(lst, test):
    return ( pair[0] for pair in zip(range(len(lst)), lst) if test(pair[1]) )
```

Usage:

```
>>> global_index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], lambda x: x>3)
<generator object <genexpr> at ...>
>>> list(_)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Get pythonic:
def global_index(lst, test):
    return (idx for idx, val in enumerate(lst) if test(val) )

Comment: filter(lambda x: x>3, [1,2,3,4,5,6])