# return index and value from array

Tags: multidimensional-array, indexing, geospatial

So, the goal here is to iterate through each row of a DEM (or any spatially referenced array), find the smallest value (e.g. low point), and then return the value and the related index.

This is not elegant, but I can get the values easily enough with a loop and seed:

```
`lowpts=[]
low=99999
for i in range(len(DEM)):
    for j in range(len(DEM)):
        low1 = DEM[i][j]
        if low1 < low:
            low = low1
    lowpts.append(low)`
```

But now how do I retain the [i][j] index associated with each value?

Ideally, the return would be [[i,j,value],......]

I have tried enumerate() but not sure how to implement it correctly. And I have to be aware of possible duplicate values, so I cannot just .index the lowpts array (akin to [Python: finding an element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604802/python-finding-an-element-in-an-array)).

Answer (score 1):

you are giving the answer in your own question!

```
lowpts=[]
low=99999
for i in range(len(DEM)):
    for j in range(len(DEM)):
        low1 = DEM[i][j]
        if low1 < low:
            low = low1
            low_i = i
            low_j = j
    lowpts.append([i,j,low])
```